# Convert a String that has Double Value to Long datatype in Jackson

Tags: jackson

I have a JSON String like this.

```
{"impressions" : "234.45" , "discount" : "123", "rate" : "123.2"}
```

I have the POJO as follows.

```
public class sample {
   private Long impressions;
   private Long discount;
   private Doube rate;   }
```

I am deserializing the JSON to POJO using an object mapper. It fails because impressions datatype is Long in the POJO whereas the type is String in the POJO and the string has a double value.

The following is the exception that I see.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `long` from String

Can you please help me how can I convert the impressions to Long while deserialising in the object mapper?

Comment: impressions is `double`, are you sure that you want it to be `long`?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from this post https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization. You can make a simple custom deserialization like this:

```
public class Demo5Test {

    @Test
    void name() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String data = "{\"impressions\" : \"234.45\" , \"discount\" : \"123\", \"rate\" : \"123.2\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Sample sample = mapper.readValue(data, Sample.class);
        System.out.println(sample);
    }
    
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SampleDeserializer.class)
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    static class Sample{
        public double impressions;
        public long discount;
        public double rate;
    }
    
    private static class SampleDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Sample> {
    
        public SampleDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }
    
        public SampleDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
            super(vc);
        }
    
        @Override
        public Sample deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext cxt) throws IOException {
            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            double impressions = Double.parseDouble(node.get("impressions").asText());
            long discount = Long.parseLong(node.get("discount").asText());
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(node.get("rate").asText());
            return new Sample(impressions, discount, rate);
        }
    }
}
```